# Failure doing FTP publish of Azure Web App

Tags: azure, ftp

The credentials downloaded from the Azure portal for Web Apps do not work for FTP.

I have tried a number of my free web sites and all of them net the FTP error "530 User cannot log in."

If I set a deployment credential then that works with FTP, but that is really a stand-in for my main login. I want to use the site by site credentials.

From the downloaded publish profile I can use the web app publish method, just not the FTP method. And, the password is the same for both (the username has a leading $ for FTP).

Thoughts?

Comment: Is this in the classic or ARM portal? The username should be in the format site\$ftp_user.

Answer (score 1):

I see that another person already commented about the username format, i.e. Site\User

That would be my first suggestion.

Other suggestions:

- make sure the site name has the complete domain name, but without the ftp:// prefix
- make sure that you have 21 as the port number (default)

What FTP client do you use? I use FileZilla without any issues.

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be a limitation in the corporate firewall for the length of an FTP password. The max length was increased and all now works correctly.